# How to initialize a map with dateTime.date as key and list of strings as value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried =

```
date_dict = {}

date_dict = defaultdict(datetime.date, list)
```

but none seems to be working.

I need to add values such that :

```
{
datetime.date(2018, 1, 2): ['name-20180102_000012', 'name-20180102'], 
datetime.date(2020, 2, 4): ['test'], 
datetime.date(2018, 1, 1): ['name-20180101_000012', 'name-20180101_000016'], 
datetime.date(2018, 2, 13): ['name-20180213']}
```

via:

```
def _get_dates(name):
    DATE_FORMATS = ['%Y%m%d', '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S']
    for date_format in DATE_FORMATS:
        try:
            date_of_index = datetime.strptime(name.split('-')[-1], date_format).date()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            break
    else:
        date_of_index = date.today()
    return date_of_index

date_dict = {}
index_list = ['test', 
'name-20180213', 
'name-20180102_000012', 
'name-20180102', 
'name-20180101_000012', 
'name-20180101_000016'] 
for name in index_list:
   date_dict[_get_dates(name)].append(name)


excluded_names = ['name-20180102_000012']
import itertools
def _get_list_to_delete_from(date_dict, index_to_keep):
    keys_to_delete = sorted(date_dict(), reverse=True)[index_to_keep:] #I need to keep the dates
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([date_dict[key] for key in keys_to_delete]))

if excluded_names in _get_list_to_delete_from(date_dict, 2):
    for values in date_dict.values():
                for v in values:
                    if v in excluded_names:
                        values.remove(v) # not working with defaultdict(list) or defaultdict([]:lambda)
```

Comment: That’s not what `defaultdict` is used for, it’s unclear to me what you’re trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Python isn't strongly typed. You can just create the `default_dict` and start using `datetime.date` values as keys and lists as values. Your code isn't working because you `.append` to a value even if it doesn't exist - you can start the dict as `defaultdict(list)` initialising new items to start as an empty list.

So, your line:

```
date_dict = {}
```

Should be

```
data_dict = defaultdict(list)
```

(had `lambda: []` previously instead of `list`, but of course the type itself functions just as well to initialise, since `list()` also returns a new list)

Also, your `_get_dates` only gets a single date and it discards the time, so it may as well ignore it. Here's a working example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime, date


def _get_date(name):
    try:
        _ = name.index('-')
        return datetime.strptime(name.split('-')[-1][:8], '%Y%m%d').date()
    except ValueError:
        return None


def main():
    date_dict = defaultdict(list)
    index_list = [
        'test',
        'name-20180213',
        'name-20180102_000012',
        'name-20180102',
        'name-20180101_000012',
        'name-20180101_000016'
    ]
    for name in index_list:
        date_dict[_get_date(name)].append(name)

    print(date_dict)


main()
```

If you're looking to exclude some names, you could just have the loop be like this:

```
    for name in index_list:
        if name not in excluded_names:
            date_dict[_get_date(name)].append(name)
```

Or if you need to remove them later:

```
    for name in excluded_names:
         date_dict[_get_date(name)].remove(name)
```

Comment: Why not just `defaultdict(list)` instead of `defaultdict(lambda: [])`?

Comment: The issue with this defaultdict(list) or defaultdict(lambda: []) is I can't remove a particular value from values list. Tats why looking for some other way to initialize.

Comment: @user3407267 what do you mean you can't remove a particular value from values? It's very simple to remove a value from a `dict` (or `defaultdict`), i.e. `del d[key]`?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the .append method.

Here's a quick fix:

```
for name in index_list:
   date_dict[_get_dates(name)] = name
```

Comment: This doesn't add multiple values to the same key.

Comment: hmmm i'm not entirely sure what it is that you want to do then? You've asked "how to initialize a dictionary with dateTime.date as key and list of strings as value" 

and that for loop above does that. Do you also want to get a previously initialised dictionary and append to the list inside?

Comment: The for loop u mentioned just takes 1 value not list of string.

Comment: {datetime.date(2018, 1, 2): 'name-20180102', datetime.date(2020, 2, 4): 'test', datetime.date(2018, 1, 1): 'name-20180101_000016', datetime.date(2018, 2, 13): 'name-20180213'} is the output of ur method. It just takes 1 value